# ML to find relationship between a number and 50 other characteristics values

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I have 10K records of football Players, their market value and about 50+ characteristics values of each player (i.e. Shot Power, Attacking, Defending, Position, Stamina and etc.) --> 80% are numerical values out of 100, 20% are categorical.

**My goal** is to know what features (or group of features?) most contributing to player value? I'm assuming it might be certain characteristics, or certain group of characteristics -- when they are high, it increases player value. Or both.

How to tackle this task? What ML models (or others) I should explore? Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a simple linear regression. Take your characteristic values as inputs (hot-encode the categorical ones or numerical-encode them if they're ordinal) and predict the target that is the player value (assuming it's a continuous variable target). Make sure before training you scale all your input values between 0 and 1.

Once you've trained your linear regression take a look at the coefficients of each variable on the trained model. The absolute value of these coefficients represent how "important" that characteristic is to the target player value. If it's a large negative coefficient - having a lot of that characteristic negatively impacts player value, while if it's large positive having a lot positively effects player value. Low absolute values represents characteristics that have very little impact. The reason you want to scale your input values between 0 and 1 is to make sure you can effectively compare the raw value of your coefficients knowing the inputs are all on the same scale.

Comment: Thanks weareglenn! Got you! Sounds straightforward. One question though, what about detecting impact of multiple characteristics together? I mean, each one of them might not affect the player value much... but when they are all high/low, theyll impact the value. How to tackle that?

Comment: That task might get a little bit more complicated - for one you could cluster your players using some unsupervised learning approach. If there's a cluster of similar players who all share high value then you could propose that the definition of their cluster leads to high value.

Comment: Ah i see, did bit of research. So i might need to classify the players, based on value.. then do clustering for each group to see what characteristics are contributing more.